# Reset Azure VM password fails - cannot remote into it

Tags: azure

When I try to do this:

[image: Reset Password Azure Control Panel]

I get this:

[image: Error message]

I really need to get into this VM.

Comment: Is this a programming question, is it better placed on one of the other Stack sites, perhaps Superuser?

Comment: Can you check the error message in the preview portal by going to VM -> Settings -> Extensions -> VMAccessAgent -> View Detailed status.

Comment: This VM doesn't have the agent installed.

Comment: Password reset requires the agent to be installed on the VM, you can download it from the location specified here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832621.aspx

Comment: can't access the VM, how can I install that? For all I know, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that happen too, and if you keep trying it usually works after a bit. It may help to try a different web browser, log out and log back in again, etc.

Comment: Another option is to use PowerShell. I see you don't have the agent installed, but you can add VMAccess with Powershell following this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn606308.aspx#bk_add Let me know if this solution is possible for you!

Answer (score 0):

To install VM agent extension on your VM, please follow the below steps and let us know if that helps.
After you RDP to the VM and install the MSI (same as you would any other MSI package), use the April 2014 v0.8.0 or later Azure PowerShell release to update the VM property to indicate the agent is installed.

$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName  –Name 
$vm.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent = $true

Update-AzureVM –Name  –VM $vm.VM –ServiceName

Now if you run Get-AzureVM again, the GuestAgentStatus property should be populated instead of blank:

Get-AzureVM –ServiceName  –Name

GuestAgentStatus:Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.PersistentVMModel.GuestAgentStatus

Note the steps to update the VM property are also on the Manage Extensions MSDN page.

Girish Prajwal

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the agent installed then you will need to mount the disk in another vm and manually make the changes. There are a number of offline password reset tools available (search for 'windows offline password reset') for a decent number of them. I've never used any (at least not since Win2k days) so I can't comment on how good they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try Stop and Start from the azure portal for the VM which you wanted to update the password.